# How to extract RGB from an image and plot only RG as a graph? R for X and G for Y

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib, rgb

I am trying to extract the RGB components from an image and plot the 3D RGB histogrma using matplotlib. But I dont know how can I do it.

Here's my current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_file = 'Paw03.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)           # rgb
#hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)         # hsv

rows, cols, ch = img.shape

for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(cols):
        if (img[x, y, 1] == img[0, 255, 0]):
            break;
        else:
            print "Pixel:", x, y
            print  "R:", R 
            print  "G:", g
            print  "B:", b
            print "\n"

plt.plot(r, 'ro', b, 'b^')
plt.xlim([0, 255])
plt.xlabel('Pixel')
plt.ylabel('Quantity')
plt.title('Distribution of RGB in the image')
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work!

So, I tried with three for:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_file = 'Paw03.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)           # rgb
#hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)        # hsv

rows, cols, ch = img.shape

for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(cols):
        for z in range(ch)
            if (img[x, y, z] == img[0, 255, 0]):
                break;
            else:
                print "Pixel:", x, y
                print  "R:", R 
                print  "G:", g
                print  "B:", b
                print "\n"

plt.plot(r, 'ro', b, 'b^')
plt.xlim([0, 255])
plt.xlabel('Pixel')
plt.ylabel('Quantity')
plt.title('Distribution of RGB in the image')
plt.show()
```

It works only for the print into the for and also save three times for each pixel, and for matplotlib it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet displays a 3D scatter plot of the RGB colors of your image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

img = mpimg.imread('Paw03.png')
pixels = img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]
channels = 3
data = np.reshape(img[:, :, :channels], (pixels, channels))

histo_rgb, _ = np.histogramdd(data, bins=256)
r, g, b = np.nonzero(histo_rgb)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(r, g, b)
ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Blue')
plt.title('RGB colors')
plt.show()
```

This is what you get when you run the code above (the result obviously depends on the particular image used):
[image: 3D scatter plot of the RGB colors of an image]

If your goal is to visualize in 3D the 2D histogram of the intensities of the red and green channels, then you may find this code useful:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

img = mpimg.imread('Paw03.png')
pixels = img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]
channels = 3
data = np.reshape(img[:, :, :channels], (pixels, channels))

histo_rgb, _ = np.histogramdd(data, bins=256)
histo_rg = np.sum(histo_rgb, 2)
levels = np.arange(256)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for g in levels:
    ax.bar(levels, histo_rg[:, g], zs=g, zdir='y', color='r')
ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Number of pixels')
plt.show()
```

And here is the corresponding output:
[image: 3D representation of the joint RG histogram of an image]

Comment: I tried, it returned to me an output like a histogram. But I want to print like this image: http://machinethatsees.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/how-to-plot-color-in-3d-rgb-color-space.html but in 2D. Therefore, R for the X axis and G for Y axis. Did you understand me? If you can help, my email is: lucas.roberto.lrc@gmail.com . We can communicate easier there than here. Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the values R, g, and b are set in your code example. Also it looks like plot.plot(r,'ro',b,'b^') would not be plotting series but a single point.

Comment: I'm trying to show the R and G distribuition as a graph, using matplotlib. The RGB values comes from the numpy array from the image.