# Plotting Chrominance by Boundary And Background

Tags: python, matplotlib

Post I am referring to: [How to extract RGB from an image and plot only RG as a graph? R for X and G for Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700674/how-to-extract-rgb-from-a-image-and-plot-only-rg-as-a-graph-r-for-x-and-g-for-y/37950005#37950005)

I modified it to just be 2d and read the Y Cr Cb values, however plotting it in 3d is no big deal main thing is just plotting the Cb Cr values and doing it based on those boundaries I posted.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Variables
Y_MIN = 80
Y_MAX = 255
Cb_MIN = 85
Cb_MAX = 135
Cr_MIN = 135
Cr_MAX = 180

img = mpimg.imread('Webcam.png')
YCR_CB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
pixels = YCR_CB.shape[0]*YCR_CB.shape[1]
channels = 3
data = np.reshape(YCR_CB[:, :, :channels], (pixels, channels))

histo_rgb, _ = np.histogramdd(data, bins=256)
Y, Cb, Cr = np.nonzero(histo_rgb)

plt.scatter(Cb, Cr)
plt.title('Chrominance')
plt.show()
```

I want to take this and make it plot the (Cb, Cr) values that fall within 
(( Y > Y_MIN) & (Cb > Cb_MIN) & (Cb < Cb_MAX) & (Cr > Cr_MIN) & (Cr < Cr_MAX))
as one color and plot the rest of the points that do not fall within these boundaries as another.  Thank you ahead of time for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace the last 3 lines of your code, with these lines:

```
crit0 = Y > Y_MIN
crit1 = np.logical_and(Cb > Cb_MIN, Cb < Cb_MAX)
crit2 = np.logical_and(Cr > Cr_MIN, Cr < Cr_MAX)

tot_crit = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(crit0, crit1), crit2)
i = np.where(tot_crit)
j = np.where(np.invert(tot_crit))

plt.scatter(Cb[i], Cr[i])
plt.scatter(Cb[j], Cr[j], c='r')
plt.title('Chrominance')
plt.show()
```